# An example for a complex-valued test function

Tags: real-analysis

Does anyone have an easy example for a complex-valued test function $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$? By test function I mean a $C^\infty$-function with compact support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you take usual test function and multiply it by complex number? If you want something more reasonable take two real valued test functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ and consider $f=f_1+i f_2$. This is complex valued test function because its support is contained in $\operatorname{supp}(f_1)\cup\operatorname{supp}(f_2)$. In fact every complex valued test function can be obtained by this procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Norbert gives a nice answer. I would like to remark, and this is what might confuse you, is that a (non-zero) test functions can never be analytic. This is because the only analytic functions that are constant in some interval, are constant everywhere.